# "ORA-01031: insufficient privileges" at connection.Open();

Tags: c#, oracle10g, ado, dbproviderfactories

I'm trying to connect to ORACLE 10g database on Windows 7 64x version from C# Desktop application using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client as SYSDBA.

here is my connection string from config file:

```
<add name="default" connectionString="User Id=scott;Password=tiger;DBA Privilege=SYSDBA;Data Source=(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = sherif-PC)(PORT = 1521)))(CONNECT_DATA =(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME =orcl2)));" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client"/>
```

and here is the code:

```
 ConnectionStringSettings ConnectString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["default"];
            _dbFact = DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(ConnectString.ProviderName);
            _con = _dbFact.CreateConnection();
            _con.ConnectionString = ConnectString.ConnectionString;
            using (_con)
            {
                _con.Open();
                using (_cmd = _con.CreateCommand())
                {
                    _cmd.CommandText = "select * from EMP;";
                    using (IDataReader reader = _cmd.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        res = reader.GetString(1);
                    }
                }
                _con.Close();

                MessageBox.Show(res);
            }
```

I must use DbProviderFactory as it must be general solution for different kind of dbs

Comment: Also, here is ORACLE_HOME environment Variable "D:\oracle\product\10.2.0\db_2\BIN;"

Comment: The SCOTT user doesn't have sysdba privileges by default. If you haven't granted them then the error message is correct. Simply don't try to connect as if the user was privileged and everything will be fine... (assuming everything else is correct!)

Comment: Excellent, how come I didn't recognize that! Ben you are the man :)